# Sticky navbar doesnt work properly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]
When I scroll the sticky navigation bar stick to top but what I want is the width not to overflow. The left side doesn't overflow but the right one does and fixed to right. Can you guide me?

Here is the code:

```
.navbar-default.affix {
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    position: fixed;    
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:15;
}
```

```
<div id="navigation">            
    <div  class="navbar navbar-default" id="navbar-default"  role="navigation">                
        <div class="navbar-header" >
            <div class="navbar-brand">
                <label>(SIP) </label>
            </div>
            <!--                <div class="navbar-img" style="">
                                <img class="icon-img" style=" width: 70px; display:none;" src="<?= base_url('assets/images/eon.png') ?>"/>
                            </div>-->
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav  navbar-left">
                <li class="<? if ($uri == 'home') echo "active" ?>">
                    <a href="<?php echo site_url("home") ?>"> Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown <? if ($uri == 'aboutus') echo "active" ?>">
                    <a href="#">
                        About Us <b class="caret"></b>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="<?= site_url('about_us') ?>">Overview</a></li>
                        <li><a href="<?= site_url('about_us/goal') ?>">Goal,outcome and components</a></li>
                        <li><a href="<?= site_url('about_us/approach') ?>">Approach</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown <? if ($uri == 'programs') echo "active" ?>">
                    <a href="#">
                        Programs <b class="caret"></b>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="<?= site_url('') ?>">Something</a></li>
                        <li><a href="<?= site_url('') ?>">More</a></li>
                        <script>
                            $(function() {
                                $('.navbar-nav > li.dropdown').hover(function() {
                                    $(this).toggleClass('open');
                                });
                            });
                        </script>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="<? if ($uri == 'news') echo "active" ?>">
                    <a href="<?php echo site_url("news") ?>"> News</a>
                </li>
                <li class="<? if ($uri == 'contactus') echo "active" ?>">
                    <a href="<?php echo site_url("contact_us") ?>"> Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post a sample code

Comment: i have attached a image above, u can see there in left side it isnt fixed bt in right it is. what i want is same as left side. and i think its the problem of css which i have given the code of css

Comment: can u please guide me??

Comment: Post your HTML & CSS code

Comment: ok i have post my htm and css too.. Thank you in advance

Comment: What happens if you set the nav bar width is less than 100%? You haven't posted much css to help represent the problem.

Comment: i want the responsive so in all view that doesnt work but i have solved it after some experiment. any way  thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you were to do the following you would achieve the results you are looking for.

```
body{
margin:0;
}
#navigation{
position:fixed;
width:100%;
}
.navbar-default{
position:relative;
width:98%;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

This would give you a centered nav menu fixed to the top of your page. However without seeing more of your css it is almost impossible to tell if this is the solution you are looking for.